# _reactNative2.default.DataSource is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new react-native. I am using Android Studio 2.3.2 for simulation. I have following code, which I think is fairly standard

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListView from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class LibraryList extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
     rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
     });

     this.DataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.prop.libraries);
  }

  renderRow(library) {
    return <ListItem library={library} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.DataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
}

const maptStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries };
};

export default connect(maptStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

However I get the error

> _reactNative2.default.DataSource is not a constructor.

Comment: can You provide full code

Comment: Have included the full code. However the error seems to be in the line:

     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
     rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
     });

Can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by,

Replacing

```
 import ListView from 'react-native';
```

with

```
 import { ListView } from 'react-native';
```

and correcting the syntax error of

```
 this.DataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.prop.libraries);
```

with

```
 this.DataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.libraries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.DataSource
```

is not part of the component class use it inside the state You should use

```js
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.state = { dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']), };
```

and then in Your render function

```js
 render() { 
  return ( 
    <ListView 
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      /> 
   ); 
 }
```

update

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, ListView, View, StyleSheet, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

export default class Tests extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
  this.state = {
    libraries: [1, 2, 3]
  }
   const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
   });

   this.DataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.libraries);
}

renderRow(library) {
  return <Text>{library}</Text>
}

render () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <ListView
       dataSource={this.DataSource}
       renderRow={this.renderRow}
     />
   </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
 },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Tests', () => Tests);
```

`

update 2

now I figure it I think `this.props.libraries` is not an array it is a json object
please refer to 
[not a constructor error](https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor)

This said only That strings and arrays will Work with new key word but not json

upate 3

I also noticed that You have a typo `this.prop.libraries` insted of `this.props.libraries`

Comment: The error is in following line of code:     

       const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
            });

Comment: I think it is from assigning value to 'this'  that it is not exists in component class try it with My code and see if it works

Comment: what data is passed to `this.prop.libraries`

Comment: the line You mentioned is Working also Your list view code

Comment: OK. The problem is solved now. I made two changes in my code. used the ListView import using curly brackets and removed the syntax error by changing prop to props.